# How to include a paper (pdf file) at the end of a thesis

Tags: graphics

My examiners have asked me to include the papers I've published in an appendix of my PhD. Due to changes of computers, I only have pdfs of most of them not .tex files, so I'd like to find a way of inserting them at the end of the document.

Comment: have a look at the pdfpages package

Comment: I'd rather find a way that doesn't use pdfpages because it causes a conflict between other packages i am using you can see a MWE [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407382/pdfpages-calc-and-moactitlepage-conflict)

Comment: I don't think pdfpages is the source for the error you show in the other questions. But without `moactitlepage` I cannot test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5}]{myfile2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile3.pdf}           % Include all pages
```

See [Inserting a PDF file in Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex#2739710)

Comment: when I add the package I get the problem:

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \usepackage
               {calc}
? `
whether or not I include \usepackage{calc}

Comment: Try to load `pdfpages` before `calc`. If it doesn't work, submit a MWE.

Comment: I'd rather find a way that doesn't use pdfpages because it causes a conflict between other packages i am using you can see a MWE [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407382/pdfpages-calc-and-moactitlepage-conflict)