# pdfpages, calc and moactitlepage conflict

Tags: errors, pdfpages, package-options

I am unable to use the package `pdfpages` because it creates a conflict with another [package](http://textuploader.com/dcgaq) i am using (`moactitlepage`) that i can't find documentation for. I'd like to find a way to use both together.

This conflict manifests as:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
> <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
>
> l.3 \usepackage
>                {calc}
> ```

Here is a Minimal working example of the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry} %INCLUDE FOR THESIS
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[space]{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{moactitlepage}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{AnyPDF.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we find `moactitlepage`? But is this really the problem? The option clash has been reported long before loading `moactitlepage`? However I do not get any error message without that package. And please note that you should load `hyperref` as late as possible. `fixltx2e` is obsolete. With an somehow up-to-date LaTeX you don't need it any longer.

Comment: For me, the code is compiled without any error, if I comment out `\usepackage{moactitlepage}`.

Comment: Ditto @bmv, moactitlepage is a 152 line sty file made many years ago by a uni student in my old department that includes much of the departments required formatting. After reading it it loads calc, which might be the issue, is there any way i can upload  it so you and schweinebacke can see?

Comment: Please add a link to the `moactitlepage` package.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded towards the end of your preamble.

Comment: `calc` isn't the problem. The problem is, that a package loads `color` with options after it has already been loaded by another package without or with different options. But without `moactitlepage` we cannot say much more than already done.

Comment: @Schweinebacke The option clash may well be triggered by the unseen package. Isn't the `\usepackage{calc}` context giving us line 3? That doesn't look like being the file we've got in the question as `calc` is loaded much later. But I agree it has nowt to do with `calc`. This is a common error with `xcolor`. At least, I get it a lot. Though that's because I am lazy, careless and know I can always easily fix it.

Comment: I've uploaded the sty file [here](http://textuploader.com/dcgaq) thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `moactitlepage` package does not test if a package is already loaded or not. As a quick hack, you could simply load it earlier.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry} %INCLUDE FOR THESIS
\usepackage{moactitlepage}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[space]{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've upvoted, but not accepted so i can check to see it doesn't  create any bugs with the larger thesis document; **thanks so much**